# How to retain filesystem path while converting to string?

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fs::path p = fs::current_path();

    cout << p << endl;
    string p_string = p.string();
    cout << p_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When printing out 'p' the path is shown as this.

```
"C:\\Users\\tp\\source\\repos\\test"
```

But after the conversion to a string it comes out like this.

```
C:\Users\tp\source\repos\test
```

Is there a way I could retain the original form of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference's page on `operator<<(std::filesystem::path)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt):

> Performs stream input or output on the path p. `std::quoted` is used so that spaces do not cause truncation when later read by stream input operator.

So we'll get the same string by manually calling `std::quoted`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   fs::path p = fs::current_path();

   // Should be same
   cout << p << endl;
   cout << std::quoted(p.string());

   return 0;
}
```